# How to get id after saved object in db in JPA?

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot, entitymanager

I facing issue when i am getting id after saving the claimDetail object then to get the id of that saved object it is coming 0 . Actually I want get that saved object Id .But it not coming. I did not work  with JPA. I have created a Spring Boot application for scheduling .

Here is my ClaimDetails.java entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "claimtrans")
public class ClaimTrans {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}

    claimDetail.setActive(1);
    claimDetail.setVersion(new Long(1));
    claimDetail.setCreatedBy(new Long(1));
    claimDetail.setCreatedDate(new Date());
    claimDetailService.saveClaimDetail(claimDetail);

int temp =claimDetail.getID()
```

temp  is 0;

Here is my JpaRepositoryFactory.java:

```
@Service
public class ClaimDetailService {

    private JpaRepositoryFactory jpaRepositoryFactory;

    @Autowired
    public ClaimDetailService(JpaRepositoryFactory jpaRepositoryFactory) {
        this.jpaRepositoryFactory = jpaRepositoryFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveClaimDetail(ClaimDetail claimDetail) {
        JpaRepository<ClaimDetail, Long> mailAuditLogLongJpaRepository = jpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository(ClaimDetail.class);
        mailAuditLogLongJpaRepository.save(claimDetail);
    }

    public List<ClaimDetail> getAllClaimDetail() {
        JpaRepository<ClaimDetail, Long> mailAuditLogLongJpaRepository = jpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository(ClaimDetail.class);
        return mailAuditLogLongJpaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Here is my JPA Factory.

```
@Component
public class JpaRepositoryFactory {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public <T> T getRepository(Class clazz) {
        notNull(clazz);
        notNull(entityManager);
        T crudRepository = (T) new SimpleJpaRepository(clazz, entityManager);
        return crudRepository;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>org.sam.application.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

Anyone can help me please how to fix this issue ?

Thanks
Sitansu

Comment: post the claimobject entity

Comment: @Deepanjan i have updated my question

Comment: so what SQL was invoked ? aka "step 1 in debugging"

Comment: Just to note: in some databases 0 is actually a valid autogenerated ID. Are you sure there is a problem?

Comment: You dont need to do so much i will post a solution you can use JpaRepository.

Comment: No need of creating JpaRepository factory and all simply create interface and extend JpaRepository.

Comment: Did you get it ?I hope this helps you.

Comment: what is ClaimTrans?? Is that ClaimDetail?

Comment: I would suggest a read of how Spring Data JPA works instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: Had you tried any of the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 4):

The JPA spec doesn't guarantee that the provided entity object will be updated after saving it. To get the saved JPA entity you have to use the return value of the `save()` method. For example, your service could be changed this way:

```
@Service
public class ClaimDetailService {
    ...
    @Transactional
    public ClaimDetail saveClaimDetail(ClaimDetail claimDetail) {
        JpaRepository<ClaimDetail, Long> mailAuditLogLongJpaRepository = jpaRepositoryFactory.getRepository(ClaimDetail.class);
        return mailAuditLogLongJpaRepository.save(claimDetail);
    }
    ...
}
```

And your sample code would be:

```
claimDetail.setActive(1);
claimDetail.setVersion(new Long(1));
claimDetail.setCreatedBy(new Long(1));
claimDetail.setCreatedDate(new Date());
ClaimDetail savedClaimDetail = claimDetailService.saveClaimDetail(claimDetail);
int temp = savedClaimDetail.getID()
```

Also, although not directly related to your problem, you don't need to create the Spring Data repositories the way you have done it. Just create your own interface extending JPARepository.

Answer (score 1):

Write a configuration class and do something like this. Use JpaRepository

```
@Configuration
public class ClaimDetailService {


public interface ClaimDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<Claimtrans, String>{
    ClaimDetail findById(String id);
}

    @Autowired
    ClaimDetailRepository claimDetailRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void save(){
        ClaimTrans claimDetail=new ClaimTrans();
        claimDetail.setId(UUID.randomUUID.toString());
         claimDetail.setActive(1);
        claimDetail.setVersion(new Long(1));
        claimDetail.setCreatedBy(new Long(1));
        claimDetail.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        claimDetailRepository.save(claimDetail);

    int temp =claimDetailRepository.findById(claimDetail.getId());

    }

}
```