# How to do findById for autogenerated id

Tags: spring-boot, crud-repository

I have a scenario where I am consuming an event and saving the details in the DB. Now the record that is being stored in the database has the id field autogenerated `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

In my test case I need to check if data is getting stored in the DB or not and is as per expectation.
But I am not sure how will I do `findById()` of SpringBoot Crud/JPA Repository since I do not know what value got generated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can get the Id from the saved details

Comment: That is the question right ? How do I get that Id

Comment: `Details d = repository.save(new Details()); Details fromDb = repository.findById(d.getId())`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for annotation `@DirtiesContext` .

**It is a `Test annotation` which indicates that the `ApplicationContext` associated with a test is dirty and should therefore be closed and removed from the context cache.** - [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html)

Read **Section 9.3.4** - [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch09s03.html)

Check - [Example](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/dirtiescontext-example-spring-test) ans below as well:

```
@Test
@DirtiesContext
public void save_basic() {
    // get a course
    Course course = courseJpaRepository.findById(10001L);
    assertEquals("JPA ", course.getName());

    // update details
    course.setName("JPA - Updated");
    courseJpaRepository.saveOrUpdate(course);

    // check the value
    Course course1 = courseJpaRepository.findById(10001L);
    assertEquals("JPA - Updated", course1.getName());
}
```

---

BTW - how you can get the id : simply via getter method from the return type of `save`

```
EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = emaployeeService.saveEmployeeDetails(employee);
int temp = employeeDetails.getID()
```

Related Post :  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142940/how-to-get-id-after-saved-object-in-db-in-jpa)

Comment: Thanks but to be honest, I did not understood how it will solve my issue. If I add the annotation, what should be the value for `id` in `findById()`. Hope I am making sense.

Comment: @newLearner You can create the data with some DUMMY ID and then query the DB for this DUMMY id. How it will help - the data you are creating with this DUMMY id will removed from DB once done with test. This way , you can test if the data is getting stored in DB or not.

Comment: Ok. So what you're suggesting is that I myself create an entry of the expected data in the database and then query based on that. Right ?

Comment: yes ...but you can use method repository as well which can save the data for you .

Comment: @newLearner : Updated answer with one example i tried a long ago . which was basically to test the update in DB.

Comment: How does this test your changes ? How do you know that actually the DB is saving the details that it consumes from the event when you are testing it against something that you are inserting yourself ?

Comment: @newLearner : i am retrieving the record from DB with id 1001 .. and asserting is a proof that the value got from ```findById``` is actually read from DB.... what else you do in unit test - the same asserts !!!

Comment: Sorry but it's not unit testing. I am doing an integration test.

Comment: @newLearner - updated answer with related post to get id after save. when you say test case - people might refer to unit test ...please specify clearly in question

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [save](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-) method from CrudRepository interface. Spring executes this method in [transaction](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L592) and after its completion Hibernate will generate identifier in returned entity.

Suppose your entity and repository looks as following:

```
....
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    public SomeEntity(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
....
}

public interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {
}
```

After saving entity:

```
    SomeEntity someEntity = someRepository.save(new SomeEntity("Some entity"));
```

`someEntity.getId()` will contain actual record id which can be used further in your tests.